# binmode encoding: handling malformed data

Tags: perl, encoding, malformed, binmode

With `Encode::encode` there are [different ways to handle malformed data](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode#Handling-Malformed-Data).

Does for [binmode](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) like `binmode STDOUT ":encoding( $encoding_out )"` also exist possibilities to handle malformed data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's [`$PerlIO::encoding::fallback`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PerlIO%3a%3aencoding). You can assign the wanted “check” argument to that variable. When you then push a PerlIO layer onto a filehandle, the current value from that variable is saved for that layers failure behavior. E.g.:

```
use PerlIO::encoding;
use Encode;

# set a value
$PerlIO::encoding::fallback = Encode::FB_WARN;
# apply a layer under that value
open my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $some_file or die ...;
# $PerlIO::encoding::fallback can be changed now
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Quite the opposite, the copy I place here will become invalid if the linked page changes. All the more reason not to make a verbatim copy of the source.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @diosney, Did you fail to notice the link? And I don't see anything unclear in the OP's question. If you need clarification, follow your own advice instead of leaving a comment telling me how.

Comment: @ikegami, you know jolly well that overly short, or link-only answers are discouraged. Of course it's idiotic to just copy a few paragraphs from the linked source, but it makes it easier for the asker / future visitors to see how that link answers the question / solves their problems. I therefore edited in a relevant explanation.

Comment: @amon, I know jolly well that overly short, or link-only answers are discouraged *when a better answer could be provided*. And then there's blatant plagiarism for no gain.

Comment: @ikegami If my edit added no value, you're free to revert it. And a properly credited citation is neither “blatant plagiarism”, nor *necessary* (as my non-citing summary demonstrates). Anyway, thanks for *finding* that link, I learned something new about Perl today :-)